# Distributing my Mac app to friends

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, macos

Hello I have made an app in Xcode for mac (in cocoa). I want to distribute it to my friends via ichat or mail. But when I copy and sent it, it doesn't run.
I have also changed the permission to 777 but still it doesn't run.
I think there is some permission problem. I went inside my app say x.app and changed the permission of x under the Mac_OS folder.
Any help
Regards,
Abhi

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't run" ? What happens exactly ? Also did you send the "Development" build or the "Deployment" build ?

Comment: you'll need to do a production build.

Comment: I ment just copying the application_name.app file and pasting it into my friends iChat just for testing. Zipping it and sending in iChat made the application run which was not running. For real distribution we have to do the production build as u said. Thanks.

Comment: ‘copying the application_name.app file’ — note that application_name.app is not a file, it is a directory/app bundle. That’s why you had to archive the .app directory before sending it to your friends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you haven't already, I recommend archiving your application directory into either a TAR archive or a ZIP archive, or packaging it into a disk image formatted in HFS+ before transferring it.

Keep in mind that Macintosh files can potentially have a lot of metadata associated with them, and that it will be otherwise lost if an attempt is made to transfer them over a network using HTTP or SMTP as-is.

Comment: This was a simple solution. Thanks yar. Just compressing into zip and sending over iChat solved the problem easily.

Comment: Tyson: “Macintosh files have a lot of metadata associated with them…” That's not true anymore; file type and creator codes and resource forks are 99% dead, and certainly not required for a modern Mac OS X application to function. The new problem is that an application bundle is a directory tree, not a file, which is why you have to wrap it up in an archive file in order to send the application over file transfer. (Some IM clients will do this automatically—I'm pretty sure Adium does.)

Comment: Good point, Peter. It was more of a generalisation than anything else, since you can still have files with resource forks, type/creator codes and Finder metadata (e.g. labels/comments), plus extended attributes. Not to mention alias files, classical UNIX permission bits and BSD flags (e.g. the "Lock" bit exposed by the Finder corresponds to the "Immutable" flag).